# Have old php web how change mssql to sqlsrv all

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, php-mssql

```
    $host = "MyIP"; 
    $alogin = "user";  
    $apass = "password";  
    $db = "mydatabase";  
    $msconnect=mssql_connect("$host","$alogin","$apass");
    $msdb=mssql_select_db("$db",$msconnect);
```

I tried to change, I think it works, but it's very slow loading:

```
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"host", "UID"=>"alogin", "PWD"=>"apass");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $db, $connectionInfo);
```

`mssql_query` and result - how to change those?
//Character - My database Table

I get a fatal error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_query()

```
    $echo = mssql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM Character");
    echo mssql_result($echo, 0, 0);
```

Fixed login database loading, normal time.Login database work perfect.

```
    $host = "MyIP"; 
    $alogin = "user";  
    $apass = "password";  
    $db = "mydatabase";
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$host;Database=$db",$alogin,$apass,);
```

Changed mssql_query , mssql_result to:

```
    $query = 'select count (*) from Character';
    $stmt = $conn->query( $query );

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print_r($row);
};
```

I get code ansver Array ( [] => 74 ), code work good (My character yes 74) but how delete  Array ( [] => )

Comment: In this case is recommended to use PDO, thats one advantage of it

Comment: i have new xampp and install PDO, but not working old website mssql , but i hawe new website with PDO work perfect.

Comment: First off all, `mssql_` is deprecated, if you want to still using your sql server you must re code your website using PDO.

Comment: i now see Character - Array ( [] => 74 )
i want to see Character - 74